# Not able to connect to internet via WiFi or ethernet port

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, internet, ethernet

I am using DELL PRECISION 7530 which has Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed in it

Since I cannot connect to internet am writing this from another PC.

`lspci` shows there is

```
Ethernet Controller : Intel Corporation Device 15bb (rev 10)
Network Controller: Intel Corporation Device 2526 (rev 29)
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: Type *ping www.google.com*  in terminal and post the output.

Comment: ping: unknown host www.google.com

Comment: Now post the output of  *ping 8.8.8.8*

Comment: connect: Network is unreachable

Comment: Can you connect to other devices with your WiFi?

Comment: Edit your question and provide more details, such as if you can find your wifi with your device etc.

Comment: when i click in the wifi symbol (upper left side of window). following are the option

Comment: when i click in the wifi symbol (upper left side of window). following are the option
1> No network devices available
2> VPN network
3> Enable Networking
4> Connection information
5> Edit connection

Comment: could you provide in the answer the output of "sudo dmesg -l err", "lspci -v -s 0x:xx.x" (substitute the 0x:xx.x with the first column of lspci command for the two network device) and "ip addr show"

Comment: Thank you for all your help guys!! I have re-installed ubuntu and it is working fine now :)